# Filtros de ordenamiento no actualizan el estado

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

estoy tratando de implementar unos filtros de ordenamiento usando react-redux, pero lo hago trayendo el orden de los paises desde la base de datos. El problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono la opcion, por ejemplo a-z, la peticion llega bien al back pero el estado no se actualiza.

estas son las acions:

```
import {
  GET_ALL_COUNTRIES,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_ID,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_NAME,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_ORDER,
} from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const getAllCountries = () => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    let countries = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/countries");
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_COUNTRIES,
      payload: countries.data,
    });
  };
};

export const getCountryById = (id) => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    let countryId = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/countries/${id}`);
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_COUNTRY_BY_ID,
      payload: countryId.data,
    });
  };
};

export const addCountryActivity = (activityInfo) => {
  return async function (dispacth) {
    let activity = axios.post("http://localhost:3001/activities", activityInfo);
    return activity;
  };
};

export const getCountryByName = (name) => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    let country = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/countries/?name=${name}`
    );
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_COUNTRY_BY_NAME,
      payload: country.data,
    });
  };
};

export const getCountriesByOrder = (order) => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    let countries = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/countries/?order=${order}`
    );
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_COUNTRY_BY_ORDER,
      payload: countries.data,
    });
  };
};
```

este es el reducer:

```
import {
  GET_ALL_COUNTRIES,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_ID,
  ADD_ACTIVITY,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_NAME,
  GET_COUNTRY_BY_ORDER,
} from "./types";

const initialState = {
  countries: [],
  activities: [],
  detail: {},
  filters: [],
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_COUNTRIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        countries: action.payload,
        // filteredCountries: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_COUNTRY_BY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        detail: action.payload,
      };

    case ADD_ACTIVITY:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case GET_COUNTRY_BY_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        countries: action.payload,
      };
    case GET_COUNTRY_BY_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        countries: action.payload,
      };

    default: {
      return { ...state };
    }
  }
}
```

este es el componente home:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container } from "./HomeStyle";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  getAllCountries,
  getCountryByName,
  getCountriesByOrder,
} from "../../redux/actions";
import Pagination from "../../components/Pagination/Pagination";
import Card from "../../components/Card/Card";
import Filter from "../../components/Filter/Filter";

function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const countries = useSelector((state) => state.countries);
  const filter = useSelector((state) => state.filters);
  const totalCountries = countries.length;
  const [countriesPerPage, setCountriesPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const lastIndex = currentPage * countriesPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - countriesPerPage;
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCountries());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(getCountryByName(e.target.value));
  };
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setCountry(e.target.value);
  };
  const searchClickHandler = () => {
    if (country === "") {
      alert("Debe ingresar un País");
    }
    dispatch(getCountryByName(country));
    setCountry("");
  };
  const handleSort = (e) => {
    dispatch(getCountriesByOrder(e.target.value));
    setCurrentPage(1);
    console.log(countries);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Filter
        onSearch={searchHandler}
        changeHandler={changeHandler}
        searchClickHandler={searchClickHandler}
        handleSort={handleSort}
      ></Filter>
      {countries
        .map((c) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={c.id}
              id={c.id}
              image={c.image}
              name={c.name}
              capital={c.capital}
              continent={c.continent}
            />
          );
        })
        .slice(firstIndex, lastIndex)}
      <Pagination
        countriesPerPage={countriesPerPage}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
        totalCountries={totalCountries}
      />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

y este es el componente filter:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Description, Select, Input, Button } from "./FilterStyle";

function Filter({ onSearch, changeHandler, searchClickHandler, handleSort }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <Input type="search" onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)} />
        <Button onClick={(e) => searchClickHandler(e)}>Buscar</Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Description>Orden Alfabetico</Description>
        <Select onChange={(e) => handleSort(e)}>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="a-z">a-z</option>
          <option value="z-a">z-a</option>
        </Select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Description>Orden por Población</Description>
        <Select>
          <option>ascendente</option>
          <option>descendente</option>
        </Select>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Filter;
```

Agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme. Si selecciono la opcion, por ejemplo a-z, la consola de gitbash, me devuelve un status code 200, lo mismo pasa con la opcion z-a, pero en patalla las tarjetas siguen en el mismo orden inicial.

Comment: Elimine mi respuesta porque hay mas detalles a revisar, en esta funcion `getCountriesByOrder` estas seguro de que regresa con los datos ordenados? puedes lanzar un `console.log(countries.data)` antes del `return dispatch` para verifcar

Comment: Puede que ese ultimo dispatch de `getCountriesByOrder` no este llegando al `store/reducer`, no se ve el uso de `redux toolkit` o `thunks`, hay que verificar eso tambien

Comment: Uno de los problemas que tenia era que la ruta que puse en la action estaba incompleta, una vez solucionado eso ya me trajo los paises ordenados